# dcotan in gfortran 9.3.0 leads to undefined reference to `dcotan_'

Tags: fortran, gfortran

For the following Fortran code

```
Program test

  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)

  real(dp) :: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h
  real(dp) :: v

  v = 0.02

  a = dsin(v)
  b = dcos(v)
  c = dtan(v)
  d = dcotan(v)

  write (*,*) a, b, c, d

end program
```

`ifort` would work. `gfortran` 9.3.0 leads to

```
....text+0x65): undefined reference to `dcotan_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`gfortran` 11.1.0 would work as well.

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/COTAN.html, there is a `dcotan` in gfortran.
I tried to search in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=dcotan, cannot find any information. Is there any further information about `dcotan` in `gfortran`?

Comment: Firstly use the generic functions, `sin`, `cos` etc, the type specific ones shouldn't have been used since 1977 (except in a few very unusual situations). Secondly cotan is not a function defined by any standard of Fortran, so don't use it but it is trivial to roll your own using your own favourite trigonometric identity, so that is what I would do. Similarly sec and cosec.

Comment: From the documentation you have linked, `cotan` is a "GNU extension", so don't necessarily expect it to behave in the same way as things from the fortran standard. As a general rule you should avoid compiler-specific extensions, as using them immediately makes your code unportable.

Comment: You aren't using `implicit none` in your program.  Also consider adding `intrinsic dcotan`. But you certainly need to compile with `-fdec-math` as the linked documentation says.

Comment: Thanks! I should have noticed `This function is for compatibility only and should be avoided in favor of standard constructs wherever possible.` in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/COTAN.html. And, `-fdec-math` works!